# django-rest-framework hebrew support

Tags: django, internationalization, django-rest-framework, hebrew

I am trying to support both **English** and **Hebrew** in my RESTful API.

When I am trying to create a new **auth.user** in **Hebrew** it returns

```
 "{"username":["Enter a valid username. 
This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters."]}"
```

How can I add support to **Hebrew** and allow **Hebrew** usernames?

Answer (score 1):

auth.User comes from Django so it's not strictly related to Django REST framework.

You could probably override the default regex on username via the `extra_regexp` though I can't guarantee it'll work since the regexp is extracted from the model.

If not your best option is to define a custom User class and override the username (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write your own custom user class as specified [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms).

If you don't want to do that, here's a more hacky solution. The character restriction is enforced in Django's `User` model, but not in the database - so you could also disable the validator on the `username` field. Assuming your serializer for the `User` model is called `UserSerializer`, add:

```
def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].validators = []
```

Comment: I am using the django-rest-framework, so not working with forms